# Struggling to get traditional webscraping into ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Came across this [awesome tutorial](http://adrianmcli.com/2015/05/23/rails-scraping-tutorial/) that taught how to scrape via terminal *and* ROR application (first time for me) ...

So, trying to break this apart and have it backed by the model itself so I can perhaps display top 3 once a day or something (this is just playing around and not scrapping for any other purposes aside from educational value) ...

I'm confused how to have this backed by the Entry model with its traditional actions, ie, index, create, etc ... ie, so I can save 3 top titles and links per day so when you go to the index page, you can see the top three links on different days

Currently as this stands:

**Controller**

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController

  # Define the Entry object

  def scrape_reddit
    require 'open-uri'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    @entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      @entriesArray << Entry.new(title, link)
    end

    # render template: 'scrape_reddit'
  end
end
```

**scrape_reddit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Reddit's Front Page</h1>
<% @entriesArray.each do |entry| %>
  <p><%= entry.title %></p>
  <p><%= entry.link %></p>
<% end %>
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'entry#scrape_reddit'
end
```

**Entry Model**

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
        attr_reader :title
        attr_reader :link

        def initialize(title, link)
              @title = title
              @link = link
        end
end
```

**schema**

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :link

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**As I'm trying to remake it in "traditional" ROR ... clearly I don't have my basics grasped ...**

**model**

still same as above

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'entry#index'
end
```

**"traditional" controller**

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController

    require 'open-uri'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))
    @oy = doc.css('.entry')

  def index
    @entries = Entry.all

  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.update(entry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @entry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tippies_url, notice: 'entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:title, :link)
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Reddit Entries</h1>

<table>

  <tbody>
    <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= entry.title.css('p.title > a').text %></td>
        <td><%= entry.link.css('p.title > a')[0]['href'] %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

**CONTROLLER**

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController

  def scrape
      require 'open-uri'
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

      entries = doc.css('.entry')
      @entriesArray = []
      entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      @entriesArray << Entry.new(title, link)
  end

  # Here I would just save the entries
  # You could perform validation
  if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
    entriesArray.map(&:save!)
  end
end


  def index
    @entries = Entry.all

  end


  def show

  end


  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.update(entry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @entry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tippies_url, notice: 'entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:title, :link)
    end
end
```

**ROUTES**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'entry#scrape_reddit'

    get '/new_entries', to: 'entries#scrape', as: 'scrape'
end
```

**ENTRY'S INDEX.HTML.ERB**

```
<h1>Reddit Entries</h1>

<table>

  <tbody>
    <% @entriesArray.each do |entry| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= entry.title.css('p.title > a').text %></td>
        <td><%= entry.link.css('p.title > a')[0]['href'] %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**3rd EDIT**

[image]

**4th EDIT**

**Controller**

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController


def index
  @entries = Entry.all
end

def scrape
    require 'open-uri'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      entriesArray << Entry.new({ title: title, link: link })
    end

    # Here I would just save the entries
    # You could perform validation
    if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
      entriesArray.map(&:save!)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Reddit's Front Page</h1>
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <p><%= entry.title %></p>
  <p><%= entry.link %></p>
<% end %>
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    #root 'entry#scrape_reddit'
    root 'entry#index'
    resources :entries
end
```

**model**

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
        attr_reader :title
    attr_reader :link

        def initialize(title, link)
              @title = title
              @link = link
        end

end
```

Comment: Move the scrape code to separate class. Run it once a day through cron (whenever gem). Results save to database in  Entry model.

Comment: @AlexKojin, oh ... just realized I misread your question ... can you demo it, with code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a gem like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to run a cron job every HH:MM each day. It needs to run a method from your Entry controller like scrape, that will contain the scraping logic.

I would move the :

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))
@oy = doc.css('.entry')
```

to the newly created scrape method and have it scrape, populate models and save them. Something like this (actually the method you have works quite well):

EDIT 2:

I change the method and tried it. I does work and save the entries.

```
def scrape
    require 'open-uri'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      entriesArray << Entry.new({ title: title, link: link })
    end

    # Here I would just save the entries
    # You could perform validation
    if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
      entriesArray.map(&:save!)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end
```

Then when you visit the index page, you can see the newly created entries.

EDIT:

Add a route to the scrape method, like this

```
get '/new_entries', to: 'entries#scrape', as: 'scrape'
```

If you visit new entries, it should save new entries to your database.

Comment: @Jermie, (sorry for delayed feedback) thank you so much for taking the time to respond, and to tell me of the `whenever` gem. The `def scrape` method that you think works quite well is actually from the tutorial referenced in the beginning of the post. I'm trying to understand how to break it down to save it to the model's db, ie, `title` and `link` in the latter part of my question if that makes any sense?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about "breaking it down"? You want to save the entries in the database, right?

Comment: by "breaking it down," I mean trying to understand how to deconstruct the `def scrape` method so it's done in the "traditional" controller format, ie, the typical actions of index, update, etc ... if you notice in the latter part of my post, I have the typical controller `Entry,` and I don't understand how to save the scraped results into both the columns of `title` and `link` of the `Entry` model ... does this make sense?

Comment: It does. Did you try my answer? It does exactly this. You just need to add the scrape method to your "traditional" controller, and add a route to it. I will edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: just tried your answer right now ... and it gave me an error due to Entry's `index.html.erb`, stating this: `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` due to `<% @entries.each do |entry| %>` that you see in the `index.html.erb` at the bottom of my post

Comment: btw thank you for taking the time to try to help me to understand this even though I'm having trouble as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: added the current code to the `EDIT AGAIN` part so you can see the current status of code and where that error is being generated from.

Comment: @Jermie, just asking ... is there a traditional way of saving it via `create` acton?

Comment: You could, but the "traditional" use of a create action is to create one record sent from a form in the new action.

Comment: oh that's right ... forgot that. Ugh. My head is overloaded right now. Going for a short break. Ugh! Really want to understand how to also do `show` action for individual record ...

Comment: Maybe you could accept this answer, and ask a new question about the show method!

Comment: @Jermie, was going to ask as separate question =) ... sorry for not having accepted your answer ... hadn't made it work, but .. I'll try to make it work again .. thank you for your kindness!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Jermie, I'll work on it right now and see if I can make it work ... will update here

Comment: @Jermie, added a screenshot in `3rd EDIT` ... that's the error I keep running into consistently ...

Comment: Replace @entriesArray by @entries!

Comment: And you should just visit the entries#index (/entries) rather than entries#scrape_reddit to see all the entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137635/discussion-between-jeremie-and-user27307254534534534543675765).